# Удалить все числа из текста, кроме тех, которые в названии

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Необходимо удалить из текса все числа (включая те, которые пишутся через запятую или точку, например 3,14 или 3.14), но оставить те, которые используются внутри слова, например T-34, 2ГИС и тд.

Пыталась использовать такую конструкцию, но она удаляет абсолютно все цифры, даже из названий.

```
b = re.sub(r"[^\w\s]+|[\d]+", r'', a).strip()
```

Пример входных данных:
a = "по навигатору в 2ГИС мне добираться до дома 35,6 километра, что займет 10 часов"

На выходе надо получить:
b  = "по навигатору в 2ГИС мне добираться до дома километра, что займет часов"

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Было бы неплохо иметь пример входных данных. Вы можете добавить в вопрос

Comment: У меня такое получилось: `r'\b\d+([,.]?\d+)?\b'`, но оно не работает для `T-34` :) А зачем вам удалять числа?

Comment: @Dmitry, пример входных данных добавила

Comment: @gil9red, потому что просто числа не имеют никакой смысловой нагрузки при анализе текстов, а названия, содержащие цифры могут иметь значение)

Comment: @gil9red немного [переделал](https://regex101.com/r/sPVo6n/1) ваш вариант и работает (\b\d+[,.]?\d+?\b)

Comment: @Alexandr, Ваш вариант тоже работает, как надо. Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот такая регулярка:

```
import re
a = "На Т-34 с серийным номером AB45F6Z1 по навигатору в 2ГИС мне добираться до дома 35,6 километра, что займет 10 часов"
b = re.sub(r"(^|\s+)(\d+([\.,]\d+)?)(?=\s|$)", "", a)
```

Даст такой результат:

```
На Т-34 с серийным номером AB45F6Z1 по навигатору в 2ГИС мне добираться до дома километра, что займет часов
```